# FlowJs - error when casting from Array<Concrete> to Array<Generic>

Tags: flowtype

Why this error happens? If I do the same operation with single object (not Array), it works.

[image: problem]

**EDIT**
OK, here is text with additional test.

```
//@flow
type Generic = {
    id: number,
}

type Concrete = {
    id: number,
    a: number,
}

//------test 1-----------

function f(array: Array<Generic>) { }

//'property `a` (Property not found in object type See also: function call)'
var array: Array<Concrete> = [{ id: 1, a: 2 }] 
f(array)

//------test 2------------
var a:Generic = { id: 1 }
var b:Concrete = { id: 2, a: 3 }

//OK
a = b
```

Comment: Please write down code from screenshot as text, so it could be copied and tried out.

Comment: @PavelZubkou please see post edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are mutable in JavaScript, and Flow acknowledges this fact.

Given an `Array<Generic>` constraint on an `array` argument to `f`, you could push objects of type `Generic` into `array` argument from inside `f`. This would mutate array object which is referenced by global `array` variable defined as `Array<Concrete>`. Thus a failure to meet both constraints.

It depends on your task, but if value of an `array` argument isn't supposed to be mutated, you could type it as `array: $ReadOnlyArray<Generic>`. This would allow you to pass `Array<Concrete>` as an argument without a conflict, as `$ReadOnlyArray` is a type disallowing mutation operations on arrays.