# Are { [string]: string } and { [string]: (string | number} } incompatible is right?

Tags: flowtype

`string` and `string | number` are compatible, but `{ [string]: string }` and `{ [string]: (string | number} }` are incompatible.

Am i doing something wrong?

https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAqAjGALxgDOGATgJYB2A5gNya4GEBM5VtjTMAB8wDAK4BbAEZ4abbPiIBmXgG8wAbWr1mAXQBcfHYIC+8jkQAsazdoEGiPE+ihiGAYwx04DMBICGjAAUAJSqqGBgAG7+NNHEhiS8AORQcHDJbJExcVFciTwUUcRsEdGx0UqJKhTqUrGGyfU0yWBmZTnRlonWRUpszkA

```js
/* @flow */

type T1 = string;
type T2 = string | number;
type T3 = { [string]: string };
type T4 = { [string]: T2 }

function main(){
  var v1: T1 = 'foo';
  var v2: T2 = v1;

  var v3: T3 = { bar: 'bar' };
  var v4: T4 = v3;
}
```

```
13:   var v4: T4 = v3;
                   ^ Cannot assign `v3` to `v4` because string [1] is incompatible with number [2] in the indexer property. [incompatible-type]
References:
5: type T3 = { [string]: string };
                         ^ [1]
6: type T4 = { [string]: T2 }
                         ^ [2]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Reason

This is normal and expected

If this was allowed, then you would be allowed to do

```
 v4.foo = 1;
 var expectAString : string = v3.foo;
```

And you would get a number even though due to v3's type you should have only got a string.

#### Solution

Mark the objects as read-only:

```
type T3 = $ReadOnly<{ [string]: string }>;
type T4 = $ReadOnly<{ [string]: T2 }>;
```

[Flow try link](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAqAjGALxgDOGATgJYB2A5gNya4GEBM5VtjTMAB8wDAK4BbAEZ4abbPiIBmcgBIASngCGAEwDyDGFgA8AbzABtavWYBdAFx8bggL4A+eRyIAWXhu36hibmVvx2jtxg7myoUGIMAMYYdHAMYBJajAAUAJSmqGBgAG5aNMXEEaQUAORQcHDVbIUlZUVcETwURcQxzaXFShEqFOZSpY7VYzTVUU3F-UXeEb5dSmwuqEA)

Since they are read-only this prevents you to actually do `v4.foo = 1;`.

#### Note

This is the same for array, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47045925/7424948).

###### Docs

- [`$ReadOnlyArray`’s type parameter is covariant while `Array`’s type parameter is invariant](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/arrays/#toc-readonlyarray)
- [Invariance, covariance](https://flow.org/blog/2016/10/04/Property-Variance/)